# Printf with Double Formatting Question

Tags: c, formatting, double, printf

I've got the following printf statement:

```
printf("val=%-4.2lf", val);
```

However, val is never padded with spaces so the space taken up by val is different if there are 3 or 4 digits before the decimal. Shouldn't the 4 in the format specifier guarantee that there are at least 4 spaces?

Sorry for the newb question but it's been frustrating me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 4 specifies the minimum *total* field with - you also have the decimal point and the 2 digits after the decimal that are taking a minimum of 3 characters out of that 4 character field width.

So if you want a minimum field width of 4 characters before the decimal point, you'd want to use a format of `%-7.2lf`.